# How to update data in same table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update `user_placement_id` corresponding `user_placement` column that give below username. I want to update `user_placement_id` with the `user_placement` that refers to the username.

```
user_id | user_name | user_placement | user_placement_id
--------+-----------+----------------+-------------------
1       | jone1     | jone2          | 0
2       | jone2     | jone1          | 0
3       | jone3     | jone2          | 0
4       | jone4     | jone3          | 0
```

Comment: I was able to glean what you are trying to do here, but in the future don't post HTML unless you are asking about _HTML_ tables.  You're asking about SQL tables, something totally different.

Comment: sorry for that. i want to show sql table. thats why i use html table.

Comment: If you could somehow have not posted the HTML code, but just shown the output, it would have worked.  A better way is to just format your table as text, with _four_ or more spaces on each line.

Comment: thanks for your information. actuallay i am new at stackoverflow....

Comment: We figured that out :-). Now, can you edit your question and turn it into a proper question?  Remove the HTML, and instead show a text table.  Then, show us what the output looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use an update self join here:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.user_placement = t2.user_name
SET t1.user_placement_id = t2.user_id;
```

Comment: According to OP's description, there is just one table he wants to update.

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa Did you read my answer carefully?  I'm doing a self join.  If you think my update won't work, then state why.

Comment: OP's table has different values for `user_id` and `user_placement_id`.

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa I believe the OP is just trying to populate the `user_placement_id` column in a recursive way, using the value of that record's parent.  What is your understanding of the question?